# Creating CAB Files - Basic Components

Tags: windows, file, mobile, windows-ce, cab

I need to build CAB files for our Windows based inventory guns.  We currently use a trial version of Visual Studio 2008.  I am trying to find other alternatives that are less expensive so we can purchase licensed software and document the process.  Being that I am not a developer, I want to better understand how these CAB files are constructed.  What are the basic components of a CAB file in this scenario? When using Visual Studio, we simply create some folders, add files and create registry entries and build the CAB.  I'd like to have a better understanding of the whole process so I can learn how to build this files using either free or more affordable tools.  Any links or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

makecab.exe, located in c:\windows\system32

Documentation on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb267310.aspx#microsoftmakecabusersguide) about Cabinet Format and MakeCAB

Comment: Thanks for the link to the documentation. I am wading through the document but this is very new area for me.  I am trying to figure out what else I need besides the source files that include 3 directories with files and two files at the root.  Do I need an inf file? DDF file? XML file?  The cab will be used for install of an executable on a Windows Mobile 5 device.

Answer (score 0):

and also `COMPRESS` command which something like MAKECAB little brother.